# When validating on W3C django is wrapping input fields in <tr><th>

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates, w3c-validation

Here is my template code for the register form

```
<form id="user_form" method="post" action="/accounts/register/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form }}
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Register">
    <br>
</form>
```

When I inspect the html of my live site or my local environment I see the following html

```
<form id="user_form" method="post" action="/accounts/register/">
   <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="blah">
   <label for="id_username">Username:</label><input class="form-control" id="id_username" name="username" type="text">
   <label for="id_email">Email:</label><input class="form-control" id="id_email" name="email" type="email">
   <label for="id_password">Password:</label><input class="form-control" id="id_password" name="password" type="password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Register">
    <br>
</form>
```

But when I validate on W3C I am getting errors because my form

```
Stray start tag tr. <tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><inp…
```

And I see the markup has changed

```
<form id="user_form" method="post" action="/accounts/register/">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='blah' />
    <tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input class="form-control" id="id_username" name="username" type="text" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_email">Email:</label></th><td><input class="form-control" id="id_email" name="email" type="email" /></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td><input class="form-control" id="id_password" name="password" type="password" /></td></tr>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Register">
    <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use:

```
{{ user_form.as_p }}
```

That will render the form's labels and fields inside of `<p>` tags. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) give you a few options regarding output, or you can manually render the form by iterating the fields, as follows:

```
    <!-- first output any hidden fields first -->
    <div style="display: none;">
        <!-- I've wrapped this in a div for W3C validation -->
        {{ user_form.hidden_fields }}
    </div>

{% for field in user_form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="some-class">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    </div><!--/.some-class-->
{% endfor %}
```

I'd recommend giving the above a try, just to experiment with manual rendering.

Comment: as_p worked thanks! Still baffled as to why w3c's crawler was seeing that extra markup but I wasn't, and I tested in multiple browsers.